# Transmission rewrites colons in directory names to underscores

Tags: transmission

Transmission appears to replace colons `:` in (the parent) directory name with the underscore `_` character for added torrents. How to disable this behavior?

for instance:

`Wikipedia: en-2020-01` → `Wikipedia_ en-2020-01`

---

version 3.00 (`bb6b5a062e`)

Answer (score 3):

There is an open ticket in transmission's bugtracker about this: https://github.com/transmission/transmission/issues/1325